# how to connection to containerd on windows using sdk?

Tags: docker, containerd, runc

I have some example from doc : https://containerd.io/docs/getting-started/

```
...
func redisExample() error {
    client, err := containerd.New("/run/containerd/containerd.sock")
    if err != nil {
...
```

Right now, I'm working on windows, also I found some explanation, on windows containerd use something like

```
serving... address="\\\\.\\pipe\\containerd-containerd"
```

then how to use this in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

found answer:

```
client, err := containerd.New(`\\.\pipe\containerd-containerd`)
```